# Background color of styled QLineEdit flickers

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

When setting the `background-color` of a `QLineEdit` using stylesheets, there is a very noticeable flicker upon mouseover of the control. Example code:

```
QLineEdit* flicker = new QLineEdit(this);
flicker->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {background: red;}");
flicker->show();
```

This only happens when running on Windows Vista and later, and not in XP. I think it has something to do with the default styling for Windows (Aero?) applications, because setting the style to `QStyle::Fusion` fixes the problem:

```
QLineEdit* flicker = new QLineEdit(this);
QStyle* fusion = QStyleFactory::create(QString("Fusion"));
flicker->setStyle(fusion);
flicker->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {background: red;}");
flicker->show();
```

*Edit:*
I also have an `eventfilter` set up such that the control gets repainted on mouseover, and the debugger is confirming that that gets called immediately.

Comment: You really need to post a *complete* example that reproduces the problem. Something that is single-file that can be compiled without anything else. So far I can't reproduce it without your broken mouseover code.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to fix the flicker?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how to fix the flicker. @KubaOber : Even without the mouseover code, the flicker occurs. Just setting the stylesheet is enough to make the problem happen (on my machine at least).

Comment: This method seem the more stable. although other features are added to the LineEdit, like rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ran into the same problem and wanted to share a possible workaround:

The reason for the flickering of the QLineEdit on mouseover is probably that another style sheet is used for "QLineEdit:hover{...}" that still contains the defaults. Unfortunately, it does not seem to be enough to add "QLineEdit:hover{background-color: red}". The only way I found it to work correctly up until now is to use

```
flicker->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: red;} QLineEdit:hover{border: 1px solid gray; background-color red;}");
```

Not quite sure why the border property needs to be set explicitly, but it worked for me.

Comment: Just as reference: I have created a bug report in Qt's JIRA for anyone who is interested, since this should not be "normal" behavior: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-42575

Comment: This solution still gives me issues. If I set the property while the cursor is **on top of the LineEdit** (with on_lineEdit_textChanged() for example), the LineEdit will flicker at least once.

Comment: Just as reference, with the new Qt bug reporting platform the link is now https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42575

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and resolved it by adding a border to QLineEdit, like this:

```
#dont_flick_lineedit{
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
#flick_lineedit{
    background-color: blue;
}
```